# Android: No Launcher activity found! Did check LAUNCHER

Tags: java, android

So most responses told me to check that there's an activity with the category set to LAUNCHER. I have 2 activities - one starting the other, and 2 .xml layout files (for each of the activities)- I get the "No Launcher activity found" when trying to run on emulator.

This is my manifest-file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.orbliners.workout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="dk.orbliners.workout.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="SecondaryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="dk.orbliners.workout.SecondaryActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your main activity you need something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. But for secondary-activities, i can use the package-name as action name?

Comment: It's needed only if you want to receive from external app intent to do something. Please accept the response if it's ok for you. Thanks.

Comment: @JeppeRask: There usually should be no `<intent-filter>` on "secondary-activities". You *only* put an `<intent-filter>` on a component in the manifest if you want third-party applications to invoke that component. Who is going to be creating an `Intent` with an action string of `dk.orbliners.workout.SecondaryActivity`?

Comment: I see now. I just have one last question now: When i created the project, it automatically created the MainActivity.java, being the main-activity. So is it the android:name="MainActivity" that defines what file is being used (case-sensitive i suppose?)? - and this file is used, once the launcher has 'found' the activity with the category set to LAUNCHER?

Comment: Yes the file name is case sensitive and it must be the same of your .java file. If you use a complete "path" you have to use your package name: org.foo.bar.MainActivity if I have a MainActivity under the package org.foo.bar. The app is found by your launcher because it can filters the app based on the standard filter defined, i.e. MAIN/LAUNCHER.